# What this S.M.A.R.T. information means?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

[image: Terminal output]

This is HDD from my Acer Extensa 5635Z laptop.

### Is it in bad state?

[image: Terminal Output]

Is this a HDD problem? It appears every time after 2 days i reinstall ubuntu
Again and again..and than i am not able to boot

Comment: I don't see any failures there.  However, it is always good to have a back up of your data in case your drive fails unexpectedly.

Comment: my ubuntu always brakes...((( after 2-3 days after installation it starts to not boot...  at first writes ACPI PCC Probe Failed, then some blk_update_request i/o error dev sda sector xxxxxyyyyy... i thought it is because of HDD...

Comment: Actually that sector would be a problem, but those are not reported by smartmontools.  Run `sudo badblocks -s /dev/sda` on your drive.

Comment: If you see failures, your drive is going bad.

Comment: Please see that second screenshot i attached to post...

Answer (score 8):

*Edit: I did not see the second screenshot in your question when I answered this. My answer is only about the SMART screenshot, which shows no problems. Your second screenshot, however, does show some problems.*

**There are no failures or warnings in that screenshot.  According to SMART, your drive is fine and healthy.**

This doesn't mean the drive won't fail, it just means SMART didn't detect any problems and is reporting your drive is perfectly healthy.

That read-out is very hard to read and understandably confusing.  It contains words such as "pre-fail" and "old age" which sound scary, and at least one other person here has misinterpreted it.  I'd be willing to bet that a lot of perfectly healthy drives have been discarded by people who saw a perfectly healthy SMART report and misinterpreted it.

The important part is there is nothing in the `FAILED` column for any of these tests (on your screenshot, the `FAILED` column is wrapping to the next line, making it hard to read), and none of the values in the `VALUE` column have dropped down to the `THRES` value or below where you would need to be warned.

**A little on how to interpret these results**

SMART records a number of statistics about the drive.  Some statistics keep track of warnings signs that the drive might be failing, while others just keep track of normal operation, such as the number of times the drive has turned on.

For each statistic there is a `VALUE` and `WORST` column, which indicate the current and worse value of that statistic.  It's important to note that bigger is *better* here.  Even if the statistic is something like "read failure rate", a value of 200 is GOOD, whereas lower values are BAD.  That is, the value you see there is not the raw error rate but a number representing how GOOD your value is.

Another thing to note is that the scale doesn't matter.  Some statistics might have a maximum of 1, some a maximum of 100, some 200, or some other values.  So, if some statistic has a current value of 1 you cannot infer that it's *almost* a fail, because 1 might be the maximum possible value for that statistic.

All that matters is that the current and worst value is still greater than the value in the `THRES` column.  The `THRES` indicates how far the value of that statistic would need to drop to represent a warning.

Even if one of the statistics drops down to the `THRES` level or below, it *still* doesn't necessarily indicate a problem.  Some statistics might be entirely informative, rather than indicating a problem.  In this read-out, the `TYPE` column indicates what hitting the threshold in that statistic *would* mean.  If the type is "Old_age", then hitting the threshold in that statistic would indicate that the drive is old, not necessarily that there is any problem with it.  An old drive may be more likely to fail than a new one, so this may be of some importance, but it doesn't indicate an actual problem other than age.  If the type is "Pre-fail", on the other hand, hitting the threshold in this statistic would indicate that there *is* a problem with the drive - that something has started to fail and it should be replaced.

Luckily you have not reached the threshold in any of the statistics you have shown.  Your drive appears perfectly healthy.

*In this question I only addressed your questions about the SMART status. Your second screenshot shows errors that are unrelated to SMART.  That screenshot shows read errors, which may indicate problems with the drive that SMART has not flagged.  Please follow Terrence's suggestion in the comments to check bad blocks.*

Comment: Very well written explanation about SMART!  I think you covered it extremely well here!  +1

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the errors that you are getting from your hard drive there, it appears as though your hard drive may be failing.  The second image that you posted is showing I/O sectors that are not readable.

Running `sudo badblocks -s /dev/sda` will check the entire surface of your hard drive to see if every thing is OK.  Sectors that cannot be read will appear as failures.  If you notice that more and more are appearing then your hard drive is failing.

You can perform a `low-level format` or `Zero Fill` on your drive to try to reclaim those sectors.  The format is written to the hard drive sector by sector.  Any bad sectors that cannot be written to should be marked as bad and it will move on.  Once the sector is marked bad the OS will no longer write to those sectors thus no longer causing data corruption to happen.

**A low-level format or Zero Fill will erase all data on the drive.  It is recommended to back up all your data from the drive before performing this step.**

To perform a the format, boot to Live media, like a LiveCD or LiveUSB, and from a terminal type in the following:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

This is assuming that your hard drive was detected as /dev/sda.  To determine what your hard drive is, type in the following from a terminal window:

```
fdisk -l
```

It will show some data like this

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000a0278
```

After the format and if you are still experiencing those same failures or new ones, the drive is dying and should be replaced.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't a low level format ( which has not been possible on hard disks since the very first days of IDE disks ).  The fact that the drive has already relocated many bad sectors shows that it is failing and needs replaced.  Attempting to write to it now will only make matters worse.

Comment: @psusi Please read this:  http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/203931en

Comment: i tried to do format, but got this. http://i.stack.imgur.com/SV2OM.png  what is that?

Comment: @HerrFelix Your link is that of your output from the SMART check.  The format itself is just a way to try to recover sectors on a drive where they might be failing.  If you can't perform it, your drive is failing.  I recommend a new hard drive for your computer.  It is replaceable on your laptop.  [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwpSRY50kGo) shows take-a-part of your laptop to replace the hard drive.

Comment: Ah sorry... It says:  dd: reading `/dev/sdb'': Input/output error         6406224+0 records in            6406224+0 records out           xxxxxxxxx bytes (512 mb) copied, 432.584 s, 7.6 MB/s ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

Comment: So i am not able to even format my drive

Comment: @HerrFelix To me it sounds like the drive is dying.  Sometimes it is best to troubleshoot to make sure that it is indeed going bad.  In your situation it does sound like that.  I have in the past have had drives where performing the format has worked.  It is not a guarantee that it will work, but in my opinion it is worth a try.  At this point, I would replace the hard drive.

Comment: Thank you very much for recommendations! I will buy some new one and try

Comment: @HerrFelix You're very welcome!  =)

Comment: The first sentence on that page pretty much sums up what I said: it isn't really a low level format and calling it that is a misnomer.

Comment: @psusi Did you read the fourth bullet point?  My answer is about zeroing the drive.  Forgive me for using the term low-level format.  But you didn't read the rest of my response about zeroing the drive is a way to recover.

Comment: Yes, the part about calling it a low level format is a bit of a pedantic argument over semantics... the more important part was that zeroing a drive that has many sectors that have *already* been reallocated ( as opposed to still pending, which writing to might fix ) isn't going to help ;)

Comment: @psusi I have zeroed out scrubbed thousands of drives at my job and many that claimed to be bad were good and vice versa.  But I'm not going to convince you and you're not going to convince me, so I'm done with this conversation with you.

Comment: I have as well.  The difference is in whether the "bad sectors" are still *pending*, which means they could not be read, or could not be read without having to correct some number of errors ( just had a few on one of my hdds the other night that could still be read, but required fixing by the ECC so they showed up as pending ), and whether an attempt has already been made to rewrite them and failed, thus, causing them to be reallocated and no further attempts to write there will ever go to the original location.